# Run Powershell script on multiple files

Tags: powershell, batch-processing

I have the following code to add new columns to a csv file. I would like to amend the code to run on multiple csv files within a folder and output it to a different folder.

```
$source = "C:\input_folder\input.csv"
$destination = "C:\output_folder\output.csv"
(Import-CSV $source |
Select-Object *,@{Name='column1';Expression={'data1'}} | 
Select-Object *,@{Name='column2';Expression={'data2'}} | 
ConvertTo-csv -NoTypeInformation |
Select-Object -Skip 0) -replace '"' | Set-Content $destination
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Look at `Get-ChildItem` and `Foreach-Object`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.  You might also want to add a check that the files in the folder are .csv type and not something else.

```
$source = "C:\input_folder"
$destinationFolder = "C:\output_folder"
$folderContents = Get-ChildItem $source
foreach ($item in $folderContents) {
    if (Test-Path -Path $item -PathType Leaf == True) {
        (Import-CSV $item |
        Select-Object *,@{Name='column1';Expression={'data1'}} | 
        Select-Object *,@{Name='column2';Expression={'data2'}} | 
        ConvertTo-csv -NoTypeInformation |
        Select-Object -Skip 0) -replace '"' | Set-Content ("$destinationFolder\$item" + "_formatted.csv")
    }
}
```